# Summing union of counts in a correlated subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a member table that has a foreign key to various other tables. I am checking each of these tables to see if a member has one or more records in it and if they do I return a value, if not I return 0, this is all selected as a total. This is mostly working except in one place. I need to check two tables and if there is a record in either of them the query will return 5,0 otherwise. I am trying to use a SUM of counts with a UNION for this but I am not getting the results I expect, it seems like only the first record in each of the two tables is being selected and that is it.

I am using(after some help ) a series of correlated queries with COUNT() and IF() to get the total. Here is what part of the query looks like :

```
SELECT 
member_id,
(SELECT IF(COUNT(member_id)>0,10,0) FROM tbl1 WHERE member_id = m.member_id)
+
(SELECT IF(SUM(tbl_count) > 0,5,0) FROM 
  (
    SELECT member_id, COUNT(tbl2.id) as tbl_count 
    FROM tbl2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT member_id, COUNT(tbl3.id) as tbl_count 
    FROM tbl3 
  ) sub WHERE sub.member_id = m.member_id
)
as total
FROM members m
```

The actual query joins another 10 or so tables, again the only part that is not working is the SUM of COUNT with the UNION. Could anyone suggest how I should do this? Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

**First try (FAIL)**

```
SELECT 
member_id,
(SELECT IF(COUNT(member_id)>0,10,0) FROM tbl1 WHERE member_id = m.member_id)
+
(SELECT IF(SUM(tbl_count) > 0,5,0) FROM 
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as tbl_count
      FROM tbl2
     WHERE tbl2.member_id = m.member_id
   UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) as tbl_count 
      FROM tbl3 
     WHERE tbl3.member_id = m.member_id
  ) sub
)
as total
FROM members m
```

**Second try:**

```
SELECT 
member_id,
(SELECT IF(COUNT(member_id)>0,10,0) FROM tbl1 WHERE member_id = m.member_id)
+
(SELECT IF(SUM(tbl_count) > 0,5,0) FROM 
  (
      SELECT member_id, COUNT(*) as tbl_count
        FROM tbl2
    GROUP BY member_id
   UNION ALL
      SELECT member_id, COUNT(*) as tbl_count 
        FROM tbl3 
    GROUP BY member_id
  ) sub
  WHERE sub.member_id = m.member_id
)
as total
FROM members m
```

If the query has 10 joins maybe you have to think about refactoring... :-)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. That is what I originally had but I got the error "Unknown column 'm.member_id' in 'where clause'". I believe this is because the subquery with the UNION cannot access the aliased table m from inside the subquery. I'm still trying to work through this, any more advice would be appreciated.

Comment: @TheMethod check the second try. I think basically you miss the `group by` in your attempt.

Comment: Yes, thank you that did it! Thank you very much for your time and expertise. When I get enough points to up vote I will be sure to circle back and do so. Thank you again.

Comment: Also, in regard to you suggesting refactoring, I'm not sure what I could do in that regard. The database is normalized, a requirement just came about to give members a score that was weighted depending on what actions they have taken, which are represented as records in various tables. We only need the top ten. This is the only way I could think of to access each of these tables, give them a weighted score, and order them in descending order.